# How can I reduce the size of listoffigures and listoftables titles?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, fontsize

I had the section titles the way I wanted at one time, but then had to add some code for various reasons. At this time, all the chapter and section titles in my document are the correct size, with the exception of the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list of tables. The code that I added is as follows:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}    % Revision to show the bibliography as an item in the TOC
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}      % Revision to adjust the way appendices are formatted in the TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

This is the way I have the tableofcontents, listoffigures, and listoftables items set up:

```
\newpage

\linespread{1}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
```

This is the entirety of the preamble of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\linespread{1.6}
\hoffset =  0pt
\oddsidemargin = 36pt 
\evensidemargin = 36pt
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\marginparsep = 0pt
\textwidth = 418pt 
\voffset = 0pt
\topmargin = 0pt
\headheight = 0pt
\headsep = 0pt
\textheight = 665pt
\footskip = 36pt

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}    % Revision 1/2: show the bibliography as an item in the TOC
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}         % Revision 2/2: change the way appendices are displayed in TOC

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[pdftex,
    pdfauthor={John Doe},
    pdftitle={The Title of My Paper},
    pdfsubject={Science},
    pdfkeywords={keyword1, keyword2, keyword3},
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyper ref}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontsize{12pt}{0em}\selectfont\bf}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}


\title{\The Title of\\ [2ex]
My Paper\\ [18ex]
by\\ [2ex]                                                     
John Doe\\ [18ex]
A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the\\
requirements for the degree of\\[7ex]
Master of Science\\
in\\
Science\\[7ex]
Thesis Committee:\\
William Shakespere, Chair\\
Robert Frost\\
Geoffrey Chaucer\\[7ex]
My University\\
2013}
\date{\vspace{-12ex}}


\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't load `tocloft` your problem goes away.

But since you have loaded it, you are probably going to use its features. Be aware that `tocloft` changes the way the titles of Table of Contents (ToC), List of Figures (LoF) and List of Tables (LoT) are typeset, in respect to the standard way defined by the document class.

If you want to use your custom titles and `tocloft` together, you have to inform `tocloft` about that. This can be done by passing the option `titles` when loading it, that is, use

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

---

Also, as a side note, you have loaded the `tocbibind` package with the options `notlot` and `notlof`, which causes the LoF and the LoT not to be included in the ToC, but later you issue the following commands

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
```

which instead add the LoF and the LoT in the ToC.

Since the `tocbibind` is specifically designed to do these things, simply load it as

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

and delete the above lines from your document.

---

One more thing... Instead of using the commands

```
\hoffset =  0pt
\oddsidemargin = 36pt
\evensidemargin = 36pt
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\marginparsep = 0pt
\textwidth = 418pt
...
```

to modify your page layout, I suggest you to have a look at the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package, which is specifically designed to handle the page layout.

Comment: @gravityblack You're welcome. :-)